# OpenGL glGenTextures multithreading not working (with SDL)

Tags: multithreading, opengl, textures, sdl

I have `id` like a variable of a opengl texture identificator. I generate it with `glGenTextures (1, &id)` and it works fine. The problem is when i call `glGenTextures` function in a different thread. It always return 0 and not generate texture. I think it is because the opengl context is different.

I use SDL for load the image and then pass it to the texture with `glTexImage2D`. I'm trying to create a new `SDL_GLContext` in the thread to share it with the main thread, but i don't how to make it. I can modify `id` inside the thread with `id=2` for example, and read and print it, but i can't modify with `glGenTextures` and i can't generate the texture that i need.

Answer (score 3):

An OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. You can't bind a single OpenGL context in multiple threads. However it is possible to create a second OpenGL context that shares the OpenGL resource namespace and bind that in another thread. *Or* you use Pixel Buffer Objects (PBOs) to map some OpenGL memory into process address space, and fill that from the other thread.

Comment: Thanks, it is what i think, create a new OpenGL context, but i don't know how to share it with the main thread.

Comment: @Safej: Traditionally shared contexts have been outside the scope of the simpler OpenGL frameworks. GLUT, for instance does not support this feature. I believe glfw supports it, but by the time you need multi-threading and context resource sharing you have usually outgrown the framework and need to start managing your render context yourself using the actual window system API (e.g. WGL/GLX/AGL/EGL/...). Do you _really_ need multi-threaded rendering to accomplish this? Can you load the texture data into memory in one thread and then queue it up for loading into OpenGL in the primary SDL thread?

Comment: I wholeheartly agree with Andon M. Coleman on this. The best course of action would be to do I/O and parsing in a dedicated thread and have it write to a memory area mapped by the OpenGL thread using glBufferMap.

Comment: Yes, i think i need multi-threading. I want to do something like an explorer, rendering in the main thread an array of images while these images are loading in another threads at the same time, like the thumbnails load in an explorer. I'm trying with glMapBuffer how you say me, but i don't understand how it work. Thanks for the answers.